# 'Segmentation Fault' Error when trying to assign and call values of nested struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nested, segmentation-fault

Alright so I'm fairly new to C and only know basic C functions, and I'm trying to create a program that lets the user create a student-a struct- and update his/her personal and academic details -also structs and members of student struct.

```
//student.h
struct personalDetails {
            char name[20];
            char phoneNum[13];
            char address[30];
    };

struct classRecords {
        int assignment;
        int midterm;
        int finalMark;
        int total;
};

struct student{
        struct personalDetails det;
        struct classRecords rec;
}st1, *st1_ptr,
 st2, *st2_ptr,
 st3, *st3_ptr,
 st4, *st4_ptr,
 st5, *st5_ptr;
```

And whenever I run my program and come to a part where the user has to input a value that is to be assigned or called to/from the struct I get a segfault error. Here's what the code looks like for one of the examples where I assign a value:

```
//operations.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"student.h"
#include<string.h>

extern struct personalDetails det; // name, phoneNum, address
extern struct classRecords rec; // assignment, midterm, finalMark, total
extern struct student st1; // student 1
extern struct student *st1_ptr; // student 1 pointer
extern struct student st2;
extern struct student *st2_ptr;
extern struct student st3;
extern struct student *st3_ptr;
extern struct student st4;
extern struct student *st4_ptr;
extern struct student st5;
extern struct student *st5_ptr;
struct student *studentID(int id) { // identifies student by ID

if (id == 1) {
        return st1_ptr;
}
else if (id == 2) {
        return st2_ptr;
}
else if (id == 3) {
        return st3_ptr;
}
else if (id == 4) {
        return st4_ptr;
}
else if (id == 5) {
        return st5_ptr;
}
}
char name[20];
void updateName() { // updates student name
printf("Enter student's name\n");
scanf("%19s", name);

strcpy(studentID(1)->det.name, name);

}
void main() {
updateName();
printf("Student1 Name: %s", studentID(1)->det.name);
}
```

Any advice is appreciated, but remember my knowledge of C is pretty minimal. Keep in mind I do not know how to properly use pointers(probably evident within the code), but if someone could explain how to use them in this circumstance that would be great. Also from what I've seen in other posts, using malloc, and sizeof seem to be common answers to issues like these, but if possible I'd like to stay away from them because my professor has not mentioned a thing about needing either of those functions. Thanks in advance

Edit 1: added initialization to post

Comment: `return st1_ptr;` etc, these are *uninitiliased* pointers, apart from the default global initialisation to `NULL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I initialized them(not sure if I did properly), but I'll add them to the post

Comment: You've only given half the story. Can you please prepare a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I dont see what else you might need? Theres a main file that navigates the user but the only issues are when my program comes to assigning a struct value, or calling one when printing from this file.

Comment: Suggest you run your program in a debugger. At the very minimum it will tell you which line of code is causing the seg fault.

Comment: "I dont see what else you might need?". For starters, where are the `st1_ptr`, `str2_ptr`, etc values assigned? You have not shown that. This one of the reasons why we ask for an MCVE. You may think you have included all the relevant code but by definition you don't know where the problem is so you may not know that you have left out something important. Furthermore, to debug a problem we may need to run it ourselves. And we can't do that easily unless you provide an MCVE.

Comment: @kaylum as I said at the end of my question, I do not know how to properly use pointers.. I do not have them assigned to anything at the moment(that I know of)! I think I need to assign them accordingly to st1, st2, etc but I do not know how to do that properly. And I do know where the problem is, it has to be within the strcpy and printf where I assign a value or call the value of a struct because after I enter an input to be assigned to a struct or ask it to print a struct value I receive segfault

Comment: @rsorce in that case, I suggest you put together a simple program that uses a pointer variable to achieve something and ask a new question. Firing off an extensive and disjointed code like this and saying "but I don't even know how to use pointers" is unlikely to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

> For starters, where are the `st1_ptr`,
>   `str2_ptr`, etc values assigned? – kaylum
>
> I do not have them assigned to anything at the moment(that I know of)!
>   I think I need to assign them accordingly to st1, st2, etc but I do
>   not know how to do that properly. – rsorce

You don't need those pointers at all; just remove all declarations of them and replace all remaining occurrences of `st1_ptr` with `&st1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
void main() {
updateName();
printf("Student1 Name: %s", studentID(1)->det.name);
}
```

into

```
void main() {
    st1_ptr = &st1;
    st2_ptr = &st2;
    st3_ptr = &st3;
    st4_ptr = &st4;
    st5_ptr = &st5;
    updateName();
    printf("Student1 Name: %s", studentID(1)->det.name);
}
```

It's simple. You forgot to initialize those pointers that caused the segfault.